# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and unexpected token

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I really don't understand why I got twice this error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier) in the following code (shown in bold), could you please help me ? (I ran it in two different instance; one as a function and the other as simple code to try to debug further but I really don't get why I get both of this error).
Also I tried it on Edge, Firefox and Googlechrome.

```js
  function CheckUrlParams(){
   //Get the URL as String
   var **sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);**
   console.log(sPageURL);
   //Split the URL string into an array
   var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split("&");
   console.log(sURLVariables);
   for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++){
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split("=");
    console.log(sParameterName);
    if (sParameterName[0] == "WMV"){
     console.log(sParameterName);
     return sParameterName[1];
    }
   }
  **}​**
```

Comment: If you're getting the error starting on the first line of the function, the problem is probably with something before the function definition not being closed properly.

Comment: There's a non-printing Unicode character after the `}` at the end. Code point 0x5396b.

Comment: Well there is nothing else than this function for my test. I actually first place it alone then I wrapped it inside a
$(document).ready(Function({  [My tested function]  });
as i got the error with the closing } of the function

Comment: If you pay attention to removing the ** chars, and anything following the }'s, there is no syntax error - place a ; after the last }

Comment: Thanks, and what about "sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);" ? what's wrong ? Any Idea ?

Comment: When I removed that non-printing character, your code compiled fine for me. I can't explain why you're getting an error on the `sPageURL` line.

Comment: I could actually solve the issue by removing window, which doesn't really impact the effect of the function. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Found by @Barmar : There's a non-printing Unicode character after the } at the end. Code point 0x5396b

The second issue has been solve by removing window, which doesn't really impact the effect of the function.